# How to make a border bottom on the right side of the element?

Tags: html, css, border

I want to apply the border to the bottom of the `DIV`, but it has to be on the right side of the `DIV` not straight under the element. This is my html and css at the moment.

```
<div class="vmselement"><img src="img/play.png" alt="play" />
    <h2>AFSLEELBAAR </br> OP ELD DEVICE</h2>
</div>

.vmselement{
border-bottom: 1px solid ;
color: #e8b215;

}
```

This is how it will looks like:

```
element
       border bottom
```

Please access [FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ngdmo1vj/).

Comment: border bottom at the right side? You mean border right?

Comment: No it has to be a border bottom. Beneath the element but on the right side.

Comment: *Way* too vague a question to elicit a useful answer. Do you mean offset to the right? If so, I'd be looking at some `::after` trickery.

Comment: @melissabos It's not clear what you want.

Comment: I know, you want the border to be at the right side,  so have you tried border-right: 1px solid ?

Comment: Look at my explaination above, i hope this is much clearer

Answer (score 4):

Just tweak the width and thickness.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
h1::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -50%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
```

Edit: Edited to fit your request.

Answer (score 0):

Try using margin-left or padding-left in order to change the position of the border, right now you only have border.

I can't guarantee it will work, but worth a try as I never did a border-right (so to call).

as the answer above me stated, you can tweak with the height and width also.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you're looking for but I would consider using box-shadows.

In order to do what I think you are trying to achieve, you would do something like this :

```css
.wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:400px;
}
.vmselement{
    width:400px;
    color: #e8b215;
    box-shadow: 180px 1px 0px 0px #e8b215;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="vmselement">
        <img src="img/play.png" alt="play" />
        <h2>AFSLEELBAAR </br> OP ELD DEVICE</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

That way you hide the right box-shadow, and the bottom-one is not straight under your .vmselement div.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ngdmo1vj/3/)

Or else try this HTML code:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<style>
.vmselement{
color: #e8b215;
}
.color-right{
border-bottom: 1px solid #e8b215;    
width:50%; 
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="vmselement"><img src="img/play.png" alt="play" />
    <h2>AFSLEELBAAR </br> OP ELD DEVICE</h2>
<div class="color-right">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you will see - I have introduced one more `div` which is floated to 'right' with limited width. For now I have kept the `width:50%;`. You may change the width as per your needs. I suggest to keep it in `percentage` instead in `pixels`.